# JSON Schema Validation Error in MarkLogic - XDMP-VALIDATEERRORS

Tags: json, schema, marklogic, marklogic-10

Using MarkLogic version 10.0-4.2, I am trying to validate a simple JSON record against a simple JSON schema.

JSON Schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "SourceSystemName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "BatchDtTm": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "SubjectArea": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "DocumentType": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "LastUpdatedDt": {
        "type": "string"
    },
  "required": [
    "SourceSystemName",
    "BatchDtTm",
    "SubjectArea",
    "DocumentType",
    "LastUpdatedDt",
  ]
  }
}
```

Code being run in Query Console:

```
let jsonRecord = {"SourceSystemName":"ODH","BatchDtTm":"09/17/21 08:51:48:472723","SubjectArea":"Customer","DocumentType":"Preference","LastUpdatedDt":"09/17/21 03:59:53:629707"};

xdmp.jsonValidate(jsonRecord, cts.doc('/schemas/NewSchema.json').toString());
```

When I run the above code, I get error
**XDMP-JSVALIDATEBADSCHEMA: Invalid schema "": ""**

I'm not really sure what is 'invalid' about my schema. Can someone offer some insight into what MarkLogic is viewing as 'invalid'?

Comment: You have a trailing comma in the `required` array of your schema `"LastUpdatedDt",`

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter for `$schema` is supposed to be the URI of the schema document.

> $schema    URI of the JSON schema to use for validation.

You are attempting to pass in the stringified content.

Try:

```
xdmp.jsonValidate(jsonRecord, '/schemas/NewSchema.json');
```

And ensure that the schema document is inserted into the Schemas database, not the content database.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you!